# How to create a radio button that's enormous?

Tags: button, user-interface

How can I create a radio button that's enormous?

The following lines give me buttons of a uniform size:

```
RadioButton[Appearance -> Small]
RadioButton[Appearance -> Large]
```

Changing the image margin has no effect on button size either.

Comment: I do not think this is possible. Even the example in help does not change the size `Table[RadioButton[Dynamic[x],a,Appearance->Dynamic[x]],{a,{Tiny,Small,Medium,Large}}]` but may be someone can find a trick to do it.

Comment: The sizes available are very much system dependent.  You would have to revert to the generic appearance to get different sizes and even that is not without potential issues.